# Configure client machine with dhcp server in ubuntu 22.04 vm

Tags: networking, apt, network-manager, adapter

I have installed dhcp package and did the configuration. Dhcp server status is active(running). My client machine is windows 2000. How I continue with configuring client machine? Do I need two network adapters for ubuntu machine? One for nat and one for host only adapter?

Comment: Are you running two VM's one with windows and one with Ubuntu wich you use for dhcp ?
What virtualization software are you using ? What DCHP server are you using and what's its confuguration ?

Comment: Yes  I'm running 2 VMs. I have no idea about virtualization software. Iam using Isc-dhcp-server. First I installed dhcpd. Then I edited default lease and max lease time, subnet, range, option routers, option domain name servers. This should be result in the dhcp server giving clients an ip address from the range defined above.